# NSDate timeIntervalSinceNow seems to be giving inflated value

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, foundation

In my Obj C code, I want to know the time taken by a completion handler to return result. This is how I measure the duration:

```
NSDate *start = [NSDate date];

[_client asyncCallWithInput:@"INPUT" completionHandler:^(Output output, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    [recordMetricWithDuration fabs([start timeIntervalSinceNow]];
}]
```

But when I look at the recorded values for this I see them in the order of 1000s and around 4k minimum. This is obviously incorrect because 4k seconds is more than an hour and I know the function does not take that long. ([`timeIntervalSinceNow`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1407937-timeintervalsincenow?language=objc) returns a [`NSTimeInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimeinterval/) which "is always specified in seconds")

Elsewhere in the code I see this used, which seems to be giving correct value.

```
CFTimeInterval start = CACurrentMediaTime();
...
CFTimeInterval duration = CACurrentMediaTime() - start;
```

What am I missing? From the docs for [`[NSDate date]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1591574-date) "Creates and returns a new date object set to the current date and time.", so I should be getting correct value too.

#### Edit:

I just realized that the place where I record duration needs the duration to be of type `CFTimeInterval` but I am passing it `NSTimeInterval`. Maybe that is causing an issue?

Comment: I doesn't see something like `%f` in the `NSLog`

Comment: Using ``timeIntervalSince1970`` instead

Comment: I just realized that the place where I record duration needs the duration to be of type `CFTimeInterval` but I am passing it `NSTimeInterval`. Maybe that is causing an issue?

Comment: CFTimeInterval has no constant reference time. Try to use one reference (1970, referenceDate) if you want to measure delay. CFTimeInterval = mach_absolute_time pause when computer is asleep.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue in other part of the code with unit conversion. The toll free bridging from CFTimeInterval to NSTimeInterval works as expected.